# Cant use IF/ELSE in MySQL with PRINT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, printing

Im trying to print something when a condition is true in MySQL.
This is my code:

```
BEGIN

UPDATE president
INNER JOIN election ON president.pres_name = election.candidate
SET yrs_serv = yrs_serv + 4
WHERE election.winner_loser_indic = 'W'
AND election.election_year = (SELECT MAX(election_year) FROM election)

BEGIN
IF (yrs_serv > 4) THEN BEGIN PRINT "warning"
END
END

END
```

When I run this I get this error.

> MySQL: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN IF (yrs_serv > 4) THEN BEGIN PRINT "warning" END END END' at line 7

This is inside a procedure. I can't figure this out. The code works if I don't try to use the `IF` statement.

Comment: It seems a SQL related question. Not PHP

Comment: Sorry, mistake. Fixed tag.

Comment: @RedZerg: Where did you write these statements? directly at mysql client? or is this code a part of an SP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you are missing `;` at the end of `update` then `Begin` is not need for `IF`. Then end of `IF` is done by `END IF;` Only one `Begin` .... `End` is needed
try below code

```
BEGIN

UPDATE president
INNER JOIN election ON president.pres_name = election.candidate
SET yrs_serv = yrs_serv + 4
WHERE election.winner_loser_indic = 'W'
AND election.election_year = (SELECT MAX(election_year) FROM election);


IF (yrs_serv > 4) THEN 
 Select "warning"; // PRINT "warning" can be achived by Select
END IF;

END;
```